# Stop criteria in google spreadsheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code that create a listbox with information from a spreadsheet:

```
function Selectbox(NameBox ,Row ,ID ,NameSheet ,NameCol) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID).getSheetByName(NameSheet);
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ListBox = app.createListBox().setWidth(125).setName(NameBox);
  var ind = getColIndexByNamelink(NameCol, sheet);
  ListBox.setVisibleItemCount(1);
  for (var i = 2; i < lastRow + 1; i++) {
    var Item = sheet.getRange(i, (ind * 1)).getValue();
    if (Item == ' ')
      break;
    else
    ListBox.addItem(Item);
  }
  var grid = app.getElementById('grid');
  grid.setWidget(Row, 1, ListBox);
  return app;
}
```

In the line with 'if (item == ' ')' what criteria should i use for this loop stop when a cell in Spreadsheet is empty?

Thank you

Comment: in your code you have a space between the quotes. This is not an empty  string.

Comment: Cool! Does 'Been there Done that!' translate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use the following function of my library to check if a variable (string) is not empty (if that is what you mean) .

```
 function isNotEmpty(string) 
{

    if(!string)             return false;         
    if(string == '')        return false;
    if(string === false)    return false; 
    if(string === null)     return false; 
    if(string == undefined) return false;
    string = string+' '; // check for a bunch of whitespace
    if('' == (string.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, ''))) return false;       
    return true;        
}
```