# Deleted string from plain text cell in Google Spreadsheet yields TRUE in ISBLANK function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I´m using the `ISBLANK` function to determine whether a cell is empty or not. But the `ISBLANK` function responses a bit odd when the following is happening:

> When a cell is formatted to have plain text (Menu Format, Number,
>   Plain Text), and the content of that cell is deleted, the `ISBLANK`
>   function considers the cell to be "filled" aka returning `TRUE`. The
>   `LEN` function returns zero. Adding `IFERROR(1/0)` will yield in
>   `FALSE` again.

Is it possible to obtain the state of that cell in either Google Spreadsheet or Google Apps Script, so that I can build a function (in GAS) that covers this phenomenon as well.

See example file I've prepared: [ISBLANK returning TRUE for empty cell](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdFZtUHFRMHh3ZGc0bUtOSmNDUnV4c3c&usp=sharing)

Comment: I found some simular behaviour thats why I check if the value is not empty. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692403/stop-criteria-in-google-spreadsheet-script/14693174#14693174) to check out the function I use.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a isBlank function that performs similarly.

```
function isBlank(sheet, cellRange) {
  var cell = sheet.getRange(cellRange);
  var value = cell.getValue();
  return String(value).replace(/ /g, '') == '';
}
```

If you happen to have a formula or predefined formatting in a cell, the value returned on an empty cell would be `' '`(A single whitespace character). So I am stripping the whitespace before comparing the value against an empty string.